# Lucene.Net to weigh descriptions with the same word in it multiple times, higher score

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am trying to figure out how I can add more weight to a description that has the same word multiple times in it to appear first for the `lucene.net` in c#.

Example:
Pre-condition:

Lets say I have a list of items like this:

1. Restore Exchange
2. Backup exchange
3. exchange is a really great tool, exchange can have many mailboxes

Scenario:

I search for `exchange`.

The list would be returned in this order:

1. (it has the same weight as 2 and it was added to the index first)
2. (it has the same weight as 1 and it was added to the index second)
3. (has a reference of exchange in it, but its length is greater then 1 and 2)

So I am trying to get `#3` to show up first as it has exchange in the description more then one time.

Here is some code showing that I set the Similarity:

```
// set up lucene searcher
            using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, false))
            {
                var hits_limit = 1000;
                var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);

                searcher.Similarity = new test();

                // search by single field
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchField))
                {
                    var parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, searchField, analyzer);
                    var query = parseQuery(searchQuery, parser);

                    var hits = searcher.Search(query, hits_limit).ScoreDocs;
                    var results = mapLuceneToDataList(hits, searcher);
                    analyzer.Close();
                    searcher.Dispose();
                    return results;
                }
                // search by multiple fields (ordered by RELEVANCE)
                else
                {
                    var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser
                        (Version.LUCENE_29, new[] { "Id", "Name", "Description" }, analyzer);

                    var query = parseQuery(searchQuery, parser);
                    var hits = searcher.Search
                    (query, null, hits_limit, Sort.RELEVANCE).ScoreDocs;
                    var results = mapLuceneToDataList(hits, searcher);
                    analyzer.Close();
                    searcher.Dispose();
                    return results;
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I can only speak about Lucene (and not Lucene.NET) but I believe they are built using the same principles.

The reason why documents #1 & #2 come up first is because field weights (1/2 for #1, 1/2 for #2) are higher than 2/11 for #3 (assuming you are not using stop words). The point here is that "exchange" term in first two documents has far more weight than in the third where it's more diluted. This is how default [similarity algorithm](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#scoring) works. In practice this is a *bit more* complex, as you can observe in the given link.

So what you are asking for is an alternative similarity algorithm. There's a similar discussion [here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/38967) where `MySim`, I believe, attempts to achieve something close to what you want. Just don't forget to set this similarity instance to both index writer and searcher.

Comment: I created a calls that subclasses: DefaultSimilarity and then set the writer to use this new class and still it does not change. Ideas?  writer.SetSimilarity(new test());

Comment: Did you reindex all documents? Also, do you set the same similarity class for your searcher?

Comment: Yep, I re-indexed all docs and even set the writer on the searcher. searcher.Similarity = new test();

Comment: Strange... I just modelled this with Java (see http://pastebin.com/5wjAJmTX) -- if you comment out .setSimilarity calls (lines 31 & 55), documents #1 and #2 come up first, otherwise document #3 comes up first -- both as expected. It's hard to comment any further without seeing what you've actually done (and I'm not a .net guy), maybe someone would help if you provide working/minimized example?

Comment: @mindas - if you replace your document terms "one two", "one three", etc.. with the ones the OP added in his question, it returns them in the same order as `DefaultSimilarity`.  Lucene.Net [has the same behavior as your code](http://pastebin.com/4AUetsMd), also returning the same as `DefaultSimilarity` when using his given terms.  If the OP were to override `LengthNorm` (I don't think it exists in Lucene 4.0) and have it return `1.0f`, it should give him the results he wants, although it seems a strange way to score documents.